# Add single, double and triple tap gestures to all "buttons" in custom keyboard in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

I'm trying to create a keyboard the allows single tap, double tap, and triple tap.  So I want to add a UITapGestureRecognizer() to each button in my keyboard. I know how to do this manually from the xib file (add each letter it's own gesture, which would take ages) but not quite sure how to do it in the Controller.

I wrote this for double tap in the viewDidLoad() method:

```
let doubleTap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "doubleTapCharacter:")
doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2

for button in self.view.subviews{
        button.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTap)
}
```

and created a doubleTapCharacter() method but it's still not working. I also want to be able to send information to the doubleTapCharacter method.

Any help would be much appreciated.  Also, I'm very new to swift so if the instructions are complicated, I'd highly appreciate it if you can break it down a little.

Comment: you have to create **one gesturerecognizer per view**. so move the first two lines into the for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create and add the gesture recognizers:

```
for button in view.subviews {
    // create the gesture recognizer
    let doubleTapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "doubleTapCharacter:")
    doubleTapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2

    // add gesture recognizer to button
    button.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTapRecognizer)
}
```

then implement the target method:

```
func doubleTapCharacter(doubleTapRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let tappedButton = doubleTapRecognizer.view as! UIButton
    print(tappedButton.titleForState(UIControlState.Normal))
}
```

Comment: Awesome thank you sooo much!!! It's working now!! I just needed to add an exclamation mark at the end of the print statement `.Normal)!)`